# Using pointer casting to change the “type” of data in memory

Tags: rust, idioms

This question is about idiomatic Rust.

Let's say I have a file and I want to read a certain number of bytes from it:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

let mut f = File::open("foo.txt").unwrap();
let mut buffer: [u8;54] = [0; 54];
f.read_exact(&mut buffer).unwrap();
```

Now I know that the bytes at offset 14 contain a 32-bit integer (not worrying about endianness).

I have been reading the integer the same way that I would in C/C++: by getting a pointer to the first byte that I want and then casting it to the integer type that I want:

```
let ptr_to_first_byte = &buffer[14] as *const u8;
let ptr_to_int = ptr_to_first_byte as *const u32;
```

Or, in one go:

```
let my_int_ptr: *const u32 = (&buffer[14] as *const u8) as *const u32;
```

Now to access the integer, I can dereference the pointer:

```
let my_int: u32;
unsafe {
    my_int = *ptr_to_int;
}
```

I am curious if this is the way to idiomatically do this in Rust. Is there a way to access the integer value without using unsafe?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29206540/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/29307474/155423.

Comment: @Shepmaster [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307474/convert-buffer-u8-to-integer-i32#29307474) seems to provide an alternative to the method used, but do you know if it (1) has additional runtime overhead or (2) is actually idiomatic?

Comment: It's certainly idiomatic (byteorder is a very popular crate). Because it's so popular, I'd expect that it has been optimized thoroughly while still being correct. For example, I'd worry about your original code if the pointer isn't properly aligned, depending on the architecture.